# Download many files at once via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to download a folder from a server containing several thousands of files using ssh. I am using Ubuntu and I do not have write permissions on the server, so I am not able to create a .tar on the server and copy it afterwards. But dowloading all files individually is very slow.

So how can I download this folder with that many files as one archive using the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
ssh username@hostname 'tar -cf - /dir/to/download' | gzip > remote_files.tgz
```

This will run tar on the remote server, but instead of writing to a file, it will output to `stdout`. This will be returned through SSH to your local machine, gzipped and then written to a file.

Comment: If I'd have enough reputation to vote, I would definitely do ;)

Comment: Might be better to inclue the gzip command server-side to save bandwidth usage.

Comment: Concur with Jaap.  `ssh username@hostname 'tar -cf - /dir/to/download | gzip -9c'  > remote_files.tgz` might save a lot of bandwidth if you're copying text files or anything easily compressed.

Answer (score 3):

Both of the previous answers will work, but I'm surprised that no one mentioned `rsync`, as in:

```
rsync -az username@yourserver.com:/path/to/remote/files/ /path/to/local/files/
```

Bonus points is that if the connection is interrupted, you can restart and it will figure out what is left to be copied.

Answer (score 2):

Secure copy "scp" is installed with OpenSSH. So this should do the trick...

`scp -r username@yourserver.com:/path/to/remote/files /path/to/local/files`

-r  Recursively copy entire directories.

`man scp` for full details.

Comment: If I'd have enough reputation to vote, I would definitely do ;)